# How to prevent macros from hiding 'const' when casting (C)

Tags: c, macros, casting, constants

I have a macro which takes 2 args, one value is modified and to get an offset I have to cast.

```
#define MY_MACRO(dst, src) \
    do_something((char *)dst + offset, (char * )src + offset)
```

In the example above, `dst` will be modified, however if the value is `const`, the cast to `(char *)` will hide this.

However, I don't want this macro to silently hide `const` members.

```
static void my_function(const float *a, const float *b)
{
    MY_MACRO(a, b);  /* <-- this should warn because 'a' is const */
}
```

I was wondering if there is a good way to ensure a variables cast within a macro is not hiding `const`.

*Moved example solution into own answer - [https://stackoverflow.com/a/25072965/432509](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25072965/432509_)*

Comment: I doubt you'd find a better solution (using macros), as the pre-processor knows nothing about such things as `const`. Also be aware that `not_const` might get optimised away, using a certain level of optimisation and the compiler will not issue the warning anymore then.

Comment: Add function `void do_something_helper(void *dst, const void *src, size_t offset) { do_something((char *)dst + offset, (char * )src + offset) } ` and make macro `#define MY_MACRO(dst, src) do_something_helper(dst, src, offset)`.

Comment: @chux, `(char *)dst` hides `const` from the destination.

Comment: @ideasman42 The `void *dst` in `do_something_helper(void *dst, ...)` already catches the `const`, so subsequent hiding is not an issue.

Comment: @chux, I see, so `do_something_helper` is just a dummy function, this works but is a bit clumsy, so I would stick to using a dummy variable.

Comment: @ideasman42 What you call a dummy function, I would call a wrapper function.  Many a compiler would optimize the calls and the result is no performance overhead.

Comment: @chux - however you name it still has to be defined, I suppose it could be some inline function called `void_p_non_const_test`, but if you have declare and call a nop inline function, Im not sure what benefits it has over assigning a dummy void pointer, which doesn't pollute the namespace with nop's and takes less lines of code.

Comment: @ideasman42 It's just the simplest and cleanest solution. A dummy void pointer would have to be put somewhere as well and would make the macro much more complicated.

Comment: @chux Your comment would make very well as an answer.

Comment: @glglgl. disagree, the dummy void pointer is scoped and so its completely limited to the macro, without defining external functions which get into the namespace (will autocomplete etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pointer Assignment (simple)

You can ensure a pointer variable isn't `const` by assigning to a dummy `void` pointer.

```
/* reusable macro to ensure a var's not const */
#define CHECK_TYPE_NONCONST(var)  do {     \
    void *not_const = (0 ? (dst) : NULL);  \
    (void)not_const;                       \
} while(0)

#define MY_MACRO(dst, src) do { \
    CHECK_TYPE_NONCONST(dst); \
    do_something((char *)dst + offset, (char * )src + offset); \
} while(0)
```

This works with gcc, warning: `initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type`,
The `0 ? (dst)` means we don't instantiate `dst` as result of the typecheck (in case its a function call or contains an increment or assignment).

---

### Pointer Assignment (using typeof)

Its possible that `dst` is a function call, in that case the compiler may not optimize it out, so we can use the `typeof` extension (if its available).

```
/* reusable macro to ensure a var's not const */
#define CHECK_TYPE_NONCONST(var)  do {     \
    void *non_const = ((typeof(var))0);    \
    (void)non_const;                       \
} while(0)

#define MY_MACRO(dst, src) do { \
    CHECK_TYPE_NONCONST(dst); \
    do_something((char *)dst + offset, (char * )src + offset); \
} while(0)
```

---

### C11 `_Generic`

If C11 is supported and the input type(s) are known, you can ensure a `const` isn't assigned in a cast.
By omitting the `const struct SomeStruct` case.

```
#define MY_MACRO(dst, src) do { \
    (void)_Generic(dst, struct SomeStruct *: 0); \
    do_something((char *)dst + offset, (char * )src + offset); \
} while(0)
```

This has the outcome of of having typed augments to the macro (which might be useful too, depending on the case)

Answer (score 5):

What's the one thing you can't do with `const` types? Assign to them. Therefore, how to get the compiler's attention that we shouldn't be using `const` pointers in this position? Try to assign through them!

Add an extra line to the definition:

```
#define MY_MACRO(dst, src) \
    ((void)(0 ? ((void)(*(dst) = *(dst)), *(src) = *(src)) : 0), \
    do_something((char *)dst + offset, (char * )src + offset))
```

Because of the `0 ? ...`, the inserted line will never actually do anything (and with the `void` casts it shouldn't trigger warnings either), but it's a C-level expression and that means the compiler *must* check it before optimization begins; the fact it never runs, has no effects, and will be removed before code generation doesn't mean it's allowed to skip the type check. Only pointers to non-const will pass.

The value being assigned is sourced from the same pointer so that it will work with any type; since the line never runs, we won't have any multiple-evaluation problems from the multiple appearances of the name. Using `?:` instead of `if` means we can put this in a comma expression in case `do_something` needs to return a value.

Comment: While this works, its going to make `-Wself-assign` warn, so Id rather stick to my current solution (added in own answer).

Comment: Can probably do some trick to avoid `-Wself-assign` eg: `((void)(*(dst) = *(dst) + 1)` However this answer also assumes the values are pointers, which isnt always the case.

Comment: @ideasman42 maybe I'm being slow today, but what non-pointer types would you use in this situation? Can't think of much else it makes sense to cast to `char*`.